# BeautifulSoup IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def investopedia():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'}
    ticker = 'TSLA'
    url = f'https://www.investopedia.com/markets/quote?tvwidgetsymbol={ticker.lower()}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    ip_price = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last'})[0].find('span').text
    print(ip_price)

investopedia()
```

The class I used while inspecting element (in html):

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"><span>736.27</span></div>
```

**736.27** in "span" is the number I need

Please help out a web scraping beginnger here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `index out of range` error because your code can't find any HTML elements you are looking for right now. 
Information you are looking for is kept within an `iframe`. In order to retrieve the data you want, we have to switch to that `iframe`. One way to do it is using `Selenium`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

def investopedia():
    ticker = 'TSLA'
    url = f'https://www.investopedia.com/markets/quote?tvwidgetsymbol={ticker.lower()}'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5) # it takes time to download the webpage
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tradingview-widget-container > iframe')[0]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(1)
    ip_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"]')[0].get_attribute('innerText').strip()
    print(ip_price)

investopedia()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Sorry for the late reply cuz I was doing other stuff yesterday but I finally tried out your code today. Had a bit of trouble adding webdriver to PATH and I installed it again since my chrome version is 94 but I finally figured it out after looking at the docs and some youtube videos. After importing time, and fixed the webdriver error, I can finally get the required data in the website. Thank you soooo much again for helping me out!  Very good explanation in comments btw. Wish I could upvote but I don't have enough reputation.